# Converting Map to graphics and annotations in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, annotation, maplex

i want to export a map for later editing before print, so i thought about converting all the annotations and and graphics and save them in the .mxd map.

when i export graphics after exporting labels , the graphics cover some labels, and there is no option to make the graphics in back level. but when i export the graphics before exporting labels, the labels makes some displacement due to some maplex config, despite making a maplex lock on labels, it cannot be fixed.

Is there a way to manipulate graphics and annotation as layers despite saving them in the map?

if there is an alternative solution to edit map in a CAD like style before print is welcome.

i'm using ArcMap 10.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

" You can edit annotation - or setup a rule or two with the Maplex engine to not clash with other text,annotation or features"

Maplex Engine Rules

Preventing overlapping

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Preventing_labels_from_overlapping_certain_features/00s80000003t000000/

Reducing the label size

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Reducing_the_size_of_the_label_text/00s800000057000000/

When you happy with the results then you can convert into annotation.

Maplex is now standard with the Standard/Advance version of ArcGIS 10.1